# visual C++ professional

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am trying to download and install microsoft visual c++ for project developement purpose which upports only visual c++(as I was told).I am searching on google, but not finding any relevant website.where I can find and download microsoft visual c++ ?Please help.

Comment: As far as I know, MS no longer releases the individual programs, and instead they're all part of the Studio application instead. During install, you can select which components you want and need to install though.

Comment: The Visual Studio Community download should be what you want. https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/

Comment: I am aware of that.But the project we are working on needs visual c++ only.Not c++ compilers with visual studio.

Comment: Microsoft Visual C++ has always been (since the mid 90s) an editor and a set of command line tools.   Visual Studio is the latest revision.

Answer (score 2):

You mean like this one: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/features/cplusplus/

It's part of Visual Studio.

Comment: This link is redirecting to visual studio with C++ compilers.But the project requires only visual c++ as the existing code was written over there.So they are recomending to use only visual c++ not c++ compilers with visual studio.

Comment: Visual Studio includes both an IDE (editor) and command line tools.  I'm not sure you can have the tools without the editor, but once installed, you certainly can just use the command line,